# Websphere Liberty Profile CPU at 100% AIX 7.1 TL3

Tags: aix, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to figure out why Liberty is consuming CPU 100% when I enable dropins in my Liberty instance?

I tried the following (searched the Internet):

- disabled dynamic polling of config and dropins
- increased JVM heap size by adjusting Xms and Xmx
- enabled -verbose:gc to see if there are any Garbage Collection activities

There are no GC activities, there is more than enough RAM in the system, however, CPU is at almost 100% when I enable dropins making the system and/or Liberty apps unusable.

This is on AIX 7.1 TL3 with 16 GB of RAM. Liberty is the latest 19.0.0.11, even though I tried this on 19.0.0.10 as well with the same results.

Any suggestions, as I'm out of ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you can run "aixperf.sh" and post the results somewhere maybe someone can make sense of it. Or, do that and open a case with IBM.  https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mustgather-performance-hang-or-high-cpu-issues-websphere-application-server-aix

Comment: Do you have the issue narrowed to dropins being enabled? If you disable dropins, what % does the CPU sit at?

Comment: Yes, issue is only when I enable dropins. When dropins are disabled, CPU is idling. 
As a workaround, I've deployed apps to use independent liberty instance. When app is loading, CPU is at 100%, when it loads, drop to almost zero.

When multiple apps are in the same instance, CPU is at 100% all the time... I left it like that for 3 days... than I killed it.

Comment: BTW, server is EOS, so I cannot use the benefits of IBM support.
I'll keep the current setup, however, if CPU jump high again, I'll run aixperf and put the result somewhere so someone can check that out and possibly find the cause of such behavior.